# New Relic customizable board

Tags: newrelic, metric

I would like to have couple of different graphs on one page in NewRelic (i.e. App server response time for two different apps)...

Is this possible via some kind of customizable New Relics board where I can add graphs that I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely possible by embedding graphs into custom dashboards. You can achieve this by hovering your mouse over any graph in New Relic and clicking embed.

This documentation should help https://newrelic.com/docs/instrumentation/custom-dashboards

https://newrelic.com/docs/instrumentation/adding-new-relic-charts-to-custom-dashboards